# Can this glass effect be done in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, glass

I'm pretty new to Blender and I've been asking myself for quite a long time, can Cycles achieve those nice glass dispersion/matte shading like on Redshift/Octane in c4d?

Is it possible? I found on one forum that "The reason why Cycles cannot do it normally is because it’s an RGB engine and not a spectral one."

If it's really not possible then I'm afraid but I should probably switch to c4d+redshift

Anything would help! Thank you in advance!
Here are some reference images:

[image]

[image]

[image]